# Making rebuses is addictive

Tags: visual, rebus

This is a one-word literary term.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is

> [assonance/assonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance) (ass on ant)

Comment: Go to the head of the class! :)