# Rebus #16 is a cousin to a previous one

Tags: rebus

You can get a hint of what this one is from [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69991/making-rebuses-is-addictive).

[image]

Comment: Jailkidant is what I see

Comment: I have an answer but as a noob I don't know how to post the "hover-reveal" format.

Comment: Start the line with ">!" to do a spoiler

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 sorry that doesn't work, but it was an easy question.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  I dunno.  I've never answered a puzzle myself.  Sorry.

Comment: @Wordster where do you get your pictures from?

Comment: My comment was 2 minutes before the accepted answer was posted. Better next time :(

Comment: @YoutRied:  You can get them online or draw them yourself

Comment: @WeatherVane:  you can try future ones.  I'm addicted to making them!  :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is

> [consonance/consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant) (con(vict) + son + ant)

Comment: It sure is!  I have to wait a few minutes to check your answer, tho.

Comment: You're right:  it was supposed to be singular. ;)

Answer (score 4):

My answer is:

> consonant
>
>  con-son-ant

Comment: This answer has already been posted.

Comment: Yes, but Kevo beatcha to it, @Weather Vane.   Sorry/

Comment: @Wordster he wouldn't if I didn't have to ask how to post it!

Comment: (Spoiler markup is notoriously tricky. It's a bit like blockquote markup, but the `>!` must be repeated at the beginning of every line and there may be no blank lines in between.. The "real" markup, that is the line breaks, must then either be done with two or more spaces at the end of lines or with HTML markup, `<br />`. Often, formatting an answer is tricker than finding it. `:(`.)

Comment: @MOehm thanks for the edit and the tip. I had a blank line in between. Usually I experiment with format in an old post that no-one will be looking at. Is there a "hidden quote" format icon to click? It seems obvious that there should be.

Comment: You're right, there should be a button for this, but there isn't. I usually write my markup directly in the textbox. (That's one of the things where it shows that Puzzling SE really abuses the Q&A format.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stretch but

> Prison Sentence

because

> Prison + Son + Ants

Comment: Good try, but no cigar, sorry!